# PHP echo date: Function name must be string error

Tags: php, forms, date, echo

I'm writing registration form but when I need to print date to page just for them to be sure that they gave the right date it says:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in [address]

Do you have any idea what's the problem?
Here is the important part of the form:

```
<form action='/register.php' method='post'>
<input type='date' id='regdate' name='regdate'>
</form>
```

And here is the php to print it (in registration.php)

```
<?php
$bdate = $_POST("regdate");
$ebd = date("m-d-Y",$bdate);
echo $ebd;
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST("regdate");` -> `$_POST["regdate"];` ; `$_POST` is NOT a function, it's an array.

Comment: `echo date("m-d-Y",strtotime($_POST["regdate"]));`, this is probably what you need

Comment: @kamalpal -> When I did what you suggested it changed to Notice: Undefined index: regdate in [address] <br> 01-01-1970

Comment: @Rizier123 -> Can you, please, suggest me something?

Comment: @AdamOpalecký cause you don't have value in `$_POST` for key `regdate`, seems your form is not submitted yet, or your form have missing input named `regdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$bdate = $_POST["regdate"];
$ebd = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($bdate));
echo $ebd;
?>
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I will accept it as fast as possible! :) Thanks again!